# Visual artifacts when style is applied to overlapping Qt PushButtons

Tags: c++, qt

In the application I'm developing, I've got sets of `QPushButton`s that overlay each other like so:

```
resize(300, 300);
QRect geometry( 100, 100 , 100 , 100 );

m_button[0] = new QPushButton( this );
m_button[0]->setGeometry( geometry );
m_button[0]->setText( "Button 1" );

m_button[1] = new QPushButton( this );
m_button[1]->setGeometry( geometry );
m_button[1]->setText( "Button 2" );

m_button[1]->raise();
```

Result:

[image]

But when the follows style is added at application level

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);
app.setStyleSheet( "QPushButton{ border-width: 1px; border-color: blue; border-style: solid;}" );
```

the buttons are rendered as like so:

[image]

What would be the reason for this artefact, and how can I workaround it.

**Information about my application**
The overlapping buttons are keys belonging to different character sets of a virtual keyboard. These keys are raised or lowered depending on the current character set.

Comment: Why don't you hide the buttons that are not used in the current virtual keyboard? Creating lots of buttons on top of each other and raising the used one just feels wrong.

Comment: Once you style a button like that, Qt can no longer use the native OS API for painting the button. You have to style every aspect of the button manually, or not at all.

Comment: @Roku Hiding button doesn't work. I've already tried it before stacking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a [QStackedWidget](http://crpppc19.epfl.ch/doc/qt4-doc-html/html/qstackedwidget.html#details) and place your QPushButtons in that stack. Then you just need to raise the button you want with [QStackedWidget::setCurrentIndex](http://crpppc19.epfl.ch/doc/qt4-doc-html/html/qstackedwidget.html#currentIndex-prop) or [QStackedWidget::setCurrentWidget](http://crpppc19.epfl.ch/doc/qt4-doc-html/html/qstackedwidget.html#setCurrentWidget).

Edit: sample code:

```
resize(300, 300);
QStackedWidget* stack = new QStackedWidget(this);
stack->setGeometry( 100, 100 , 100 , 100 );

m_button[0] = new QPushButton( this );
m_button[0]->setText( "Button 1 );
stack->addWidget(m_button[0]);

m_button[1] = new QPushButton( this );
m_button[1]->setText( "Button 2" );
stack->addWidget(m_button[1]);

stack->setCurrentWidget(m_button[1]);    //or stack->setCurrentIndex(1);
```

Comment: Thanks! BTW, `stack->setSize( 100, 100 , 100 , 100 )`should probably be `stack->setGeometry( 100, 100 , 100 , 100 )`.